# manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I Hi All,

I have been trying to load data in hdfs using sqoop for that I wrote a shell script, I am able to perform the import using command prompt but it fails when I ran the script.Below is the script

```
#!/bin/bash
tablename=${1}
hdfspath=${2}
NOW=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y-%H-%M-%S")
echo "started at $NOW"
sqoop import \
  --connect jdbc:mysql://local/hadoopguide \
  --username root \
  --password cloudera \
  --table ${1} \
  --target-dir ${2}
END_T=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y-%H-%M-%S")
echo "end at $END_T"
```

Below is the error which I am getting

```
17/09/17 01:07:26 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Answer (score 0):

issue was with connection string correct string would be jdbc:mysql://quickstart:3306/hadoopguide